# In flutter how to do we write if () else if() else() while changing icon color or background color?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
Icon(_image == null ? MdiIcons.imageSearch : MdiIcons.checkBold,size: 35,color : _image == null ?Colors.red : Colors.blue)
```

for example the above code can shift between blue and red but I have two more conditions where i need to change the color to green and yellow also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to do it like that, you can chain your conditions like this

```
condition1 ? Colors.red : condition2 ? Colors.blue : condition3 ? Colors.green : Colors.yellow
```

but, I don't recommend it. You should extract it to a function with proper if/else syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use function for selecting color.

```
Color getImageColor(image) {
    if (image == null) {
      return Colors.red;
    } else if () {
      ... return color
    } else if () {
      ... return color
    } else {
      return Colors.blue;
    }
}

Icon(_image == null ? MdiIcons.imageSearch : MdiIcons.checkBold,
    size: 35,
    color : getImageColor(_image),
)
``
```